# Solr related data search with dates

Tags: solr

I am working on the Solr Search criteria having dates, I used below criteria for a month.

`FROM_DATE:[2016-07-01 TO *] AND TO_DATE:[* TO 2016-07-30]` – this returns approximately 481,000 records.

But, when I run the same query for 1 week at a time:

`FROM_DATE:[2016-07-01 TO *] AND TO_DATE:[* TO 2016-07-07]` – I get 333 rows returned

`FROM_DATE:[2016-07-08 TO *] AND TO_DATE:[* TO 2016-07-14]` – I get 9 rows returned

`FROM_DATE:[2016-07-15 TO *] AND TO_DATE:[* TO 2016-07-21]` – I get 35 rows returned

`FROM_DATE:[2016-07-22 TO *] AND TO_DATE:[* TO 2016-07-30]` – I get 0 rows returned

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you might missing the time.

You only specify the date, but a date can also contain a time. Implicit when specifying only the day, the time is set to `00:00:00:000`.

So `FROM_DATE:[2016-07-01 TO *] AND TO_DATE:[* TO 2016-07-07]` translate to

`FROM_DATE:[2016-07-01 00:00:00 TO *] AND TO_DATE:[* TO 2016-07-07 00:00:00]`

The same for `FROM_DATE:[2016-07-08 TO *] AND TO_DATE:[* TO 2016-07-14]` translates to

`FROM_DATE:[2016-07-08 00:00:00 TO *] AND TO_DATE:[* TO 2016-07-14 :00:00:00]`

In result you exclude all events on the day from `2016-07-07 00:00:01` to `2016-07-07 23:59:59` and the same for all the other days at the end of a week.

I expect that you get a different result when you specify the full end date including the time on the `TO_DATE`.